# Frequent issue with TypeScript and preferring import over require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Whenever possible, I try to use `import` over `require` but in some circumstances this breaks type checking. What is the correct way to handle this issue? Is it possible to cast an import? Are not all `require`'s replaceable with `import`'s?

[image: Left: Property 'get' does not exist, Right: import instead of require]

Left: `Property 'get' does not exist...`

Right: `import * as convict from "convict";` instead of `require("convict");`

Left:

```
"use strict";

import * as Busboy from "busboy";
import * as convcit from "convict";
import * as config from "./config";
import * as express from "express";
import * as helmet from "helmet";
import * as logger from "morgan";
import * as path from "path";

import * as requestDebug from "request-debug";
import * as requestJs from "request";

// [ts] Property 'get' does not exist on type 'typeof "PrizmDoc-Node.js-Sample/config"'.
if (config.get("env") !== "production") {
    requestDebug(requestJs);
}

...
```

Right:

```
//let convict = require("convict");

import * as convict from "convict";

const config = convict({
    "env": {
        "doc": "The application environment.",
        "format": ["production", "development", "test"],
        "default": "development",
        "env": "NODE_ENV"
    },

...

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Post code as **text**. Not as an image.

Comment: Added code to supplement the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an issue with the typings of one of your dependencies, `convict`. Looking at the `@types/convict` source:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/convict/index.d.ts#L122

They export the definitions using `export = ...`, which according to the Typescript handbook:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html (see the "`export =`and `import = require()`" heading)

breaks `import * from ...` imports. So, you're kinda stuck on this one.

Comment: So if I were feeling ambitious I could go and update `convict`'s .d.ts file to resolve the issue? Or would I need to actually break into their code?

Comment: Yep! This is only in the typings, so if you wanted you can submit a pull request against the DefinitelyTyped repo and get it fixed for everyone!

Comment: I was using TS 2.5.2 and fixed the issue by updating my TS to latest version. Hope that helps someone.