# Confusion about functional equivalency of `export` usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Shouldn't

```
import * as convict from "convict";

const config = convict({ ... });

// Perform validation
config.validate({ "allowed": "strict" });

export = config;
```

be functionally equivalent to:

```
import * as convict from "convict";

export const config = convict({ ... });

// Perform validation
config.validate({ "allowed": "strict" });
```

The first snippet works, but the second snippet introduces type errors such as:

```
TypeError: config.get is not a function
```

When imported using:

```
import * as config from "./config";
```

<sup>(This question and [Frequent issue with TypeScript and preferring import over require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368325/frequent-issue-with-typescript-and-preferring-import-over-require) are different. This question is about exports and what should be two equivalent usages. The other question is about imports.)</sup>

Comment: The questions are different. [Frequent issue with TypeScript and preferring import over require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368325/frequent-issue-with-typescript-and-preferring-import-over-require) is about imports, this question is about exports and what should be two equivalent usages.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry for that. I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: All good. I added a footnote for maximum clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`export const config = ...` is so called "named export", it adds `config` variable to the list of names exported by the module. You can look at various variants of es6 export statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), this particular one corresponds to the 4th line of the first example (note 'also var, const' comment):

```
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const
```

and can be used with "named import* like

```
import {config} from '...';
```

`export = config` is entirely different, it's typescript-only [export assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require). The documentation says that is should be imported as `import config = require(...)` which is again typescript-only special syntax.

With current version of TypeScript, export assignment can also be imported as

```
import * as config from 'module';
```

[but there is breaking change in the works](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19675), in the future (maybe as soon as 2.8) this import will stop working with export assingment and will have to be written as

```
import config from 'module';
```

Answer (score 1):

The two are indeed different. Essentially, it all has to do with the fact that in the second case `config` is a named export.

The first snippet produces an export that is *just* the config. If you did `require("./config")`, you'd get that config object. This is because you set the `exports` object to the config. That's why you have to do `* as config` when importing, because the entire imported object is what you're looking to get.

The second snippet produces an object with a named `config` field that points to your config; this is equivalent (ish) to doing:

```
exports = {
    config: convict({ ... })
};
```

In this example, `config` is a **named export**. To import it, you'd have to get the `config` field of the exported object:

```
import { config } from "./config";
```